# Is this right way to create sequence diagram?

Tags: modeling, sequence-diagram

im trying to create a sequence diagram for login , but i dont know if its true or not , maybe the community can help me check , because i see many way to create sequence diagram and its not the same at all ..[image]

Thank you for the help and explanations

Comment: What is the entity `ARMan Home Page`?

Comment: who is the diagram for?

Comment: Does the database really call the homepage? Or does it return data back up the chain to the user, which is then redirected to the homepage?

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence diagram is mostly correct. I only see an issue with the interaction with Database.

In your current diagram, the ValidateUser class tells the Database that the user is valid without retrieving information, and then the Database tells ARMan Home Page to show itself. I find it unbelievable that the logic will actually be implemented that way.

My expectation is

- ValidateUser makes a call to Database to retrieve the User based on the username
- Database returns the User to ValidateUser
- ValidateUser returns the validation result to ARMan Application Login Form
- ARMan Application Login Form tells ARMan Home Page to show the home page

Answer (score 1):

A couple observations

- Those should be calls (with activation boxes) that return.
- You do not have a home page actor, you have a controller.

You want something like this (code for websequencediagrams.com):

```
title Login Request

Client->+Web Server: Request login
Web Server->+Login Controller: Call controller
Login Controller->-Web Server: Response (login form)
Web Server->-Client: Response (login form)
```

[image: Sequence diagram for Login Request]

Then something like this:

```
title Authentication Sequence

Client->+Web Server: Send Username and Password
Web Server->+Login Controller: Call Controller
Login Controller->+Session Manager: Validate user
Session Manager->+Database: Retrieve password hash (and salt) and role by Username
Database->-Session Manager: Hash (and salt) and role
note right of Session Manager: Compute hash of Password with salt and compare
Session Manager->-Login Controller: User valid
Login Controller->+Session Manager: Create session for role
note right of Session Manager: generate unique session id
Session Manager->+Database: Insert session id and role
Database->-Session Manager: Success
Session Manager->-Login Controller: Unique session id
Login Controller->-Web Server: Response (cookie with session id)
Web Server->-Client: Response (cookie with session id)
```

[image: Sequence diagram for Authentication Sequence]

And finally something like this:

```
title Access to Restricted Area

Client->+Web Server: Request restricted area (with cookie)
Web Server->+Restricted Area Controller: Call Controller
note right of Restricted Area Controller: session id taken from cookie
Restricted Area Controller->+Session Manager: Validate Session (with session id)
Session Manager->+Database: Query session role by session id
Database->-Session Manager: Session role
Session Manager->-Restricted Area Controller: Session role
note right of Restricted Area Controller: role verified
Restricted Area Controller->-Web Server: Response
Web Server->-Client: Response
```

[image: Sequence diagram for Access to Restricted Area]

---

*Please do not base your implementation on these diagrams. They are, first and foremost, for illustration of how to make sequence diagrams. In practice there should be a router to decide what controller to call, it should not be responsability of the controller to check the role (plus the validation can be much more complex that just a role), there probably should be a presenter, etc...*

*If you want to learn about the structure of a web framework, I suggest [Baruco 2012: Deconstructing the framework, by Gary Bernhardt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUe6tacW3JE).*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't usually one correct way to create a diagram. Does it pass your test on

- Correctness
- Completeness
- Visual appearance

Does it convey the actual control flow?

As an observer with no knowledge of your situation, I think the database node is misplaced. A database is not an actor and control is not passed to a database. The validateuser component likely *uses* a database for persistence.